# Замена элементов двумерного списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть вложенный список:

```
field = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]
```

нужно как бы развернуть его к виду

```
field = [
    [3, 6, 9],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [1, 4, 7]
]
```

Цифры используются просто как пример. Нужно просто поменять элементы местами

Answer (score 1):

В принципе, делается в одну строчку:

```
field = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
result = list(map(list, zip(*field)))[::-1]
print(result)
```

На выходе:

```
[[3, 6, 9], [2, 5, 8], [1, 4, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

изменяем элементы вложенного списка сначала ссылаясь на индекс списка, затем на индекс элемента.

```
field[0][0] = 7 #изменяем значение первого элемента первого списка
```

Comment: вообще суть в другом. У меня есть поле для игры в крестики-нолики. Нужно сделать проверку на победу. Что бы не выходило овер много условий проверки я подумал что можно сделать всего 6 проверок в сумме для крестиков и ноликов на вертикальных строках. После чего перевернуть поле и выполнить ту же проверку. То есть в field хранится допустим поле [[-,x,x],[0,-,x,[-,-,-]] мы делаем 6 проверок каждой вертикальной строки, затем переворачиваем поле и снова смотрим вертикальные строки(которые после переворота уже являются горизонтальными, но к ним буду подходить проверки вертикальных)